# Collaborative post submission

Tags: plugins, posts

I am working for a client who wants to implement the following collaborative post submission process:

Allows public users to submit draft posts,
allows admins to give feedback and add to the submitted post,
Admins approve it as the final version,
Finally the contributor needs to be able to approve the final version before the post is actually published

I identified the editflow plugin as a suitable solution. Does anyone else agree with this? Or are there alternative solutions?